# What does Steam backup?

Tags: steam

When backing up game files trough Steam, does, it save the game directory as it is in the steamapps folder, including modified files, or does it only keep the original files?

Specifically, I've installed Morrowind with some mods, and I would like to know if when doing a backup steam will keep the mods or save only the installation files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8794-YPHV-2033) article on the Steam support site:

> Important:
>
> Backups for Valve games created with this feature will not include
>   saved games, custom multiplayer maps or configuration files.

So to answer your question, it will not back up your mods. However, the article goes on to describe how you can back up your full installation.